# Spring boot with hibernate first level cache

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, caching, spring-data-jpa

I called `CrudRepository#findById` two times inside the same method, it displayed in console one select statement.
why the second select statement doesn't displayed in the second method call.

**here is the service code:**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AccountService {
    private final AccountReporitory accountReporitory;

    public void find() {
        final Account account1 = accountReporitory.findById(1L).get();
        final Account account2 = accountReporitory.findById(1L).get();
    }
}
```

**here is the repository code:**

```
public interface AccountReporitory extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
}
```

Comment: You have the answer in your question title. It seems you already know what is going on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring JpaRepository is not returning updated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339274/spring-jparepository-is-not-returning-updated-data)

Answer (score 1):

When you make the first call to `findById(1L)` the resulting entity is placed in the session's first level cache. Any succeeding calls to `findById()` with the same id in the same session will result in the entity manager retrieving the entity from the first level cache instead of performing a database query. This is one of the primary purposes of the first level cache.